# do while loop is missing one row to read from oracle database

Tags: vb.net

Here is my code

```
     If dr.HasRows Then
                Do While dr.Read()
                    row = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
                    For c As Integer = 0 To dr.FieldCount - 1  '//fieldcount gives the column count.
                        row.Add(dr.GetName(c), dr.GetValue(c)) '//getname->gets the column name; getvalue->gets the col value.
                    Next
                    rows.Add(row)
                Loop
            End If

        End Using
```

my table has 4 rows but it misses the first one and I don't know where the problem is.

Any help appreciate .

Comment: You don't have a call to `Read` before that first `If` statement do you?

Comment: yes. I am calling dr.read()  before is statement . let me check

Comment: Just to be clear, every time you call `Read` you read a record, so that first call would be reading the first record and then you presumably discarded it, only using the data read in the loop.  By the way, testing `HasRows` is pointless if you're just going to then call `Read` in a loop.  If there are no rows the `Read` will immediately return `False` and you won't enter the loop body anyway.